# How to return multiple values from an if-else or a switch case

Tags: swift

I am still new and learning Swift so I was just wondering if there was some way I could write this code in a shorter way without repeating it thrice?

```
var meterCalc: Double {
    let lengthInput = Double(lengthIn1) + Double(lengthIn2)/100
    
    if lengthUnit == 0 {
        return lengthInput
    } else if lengthUnit == 1 {
        return lengthInput / 39.37
    } else {
        return lengthInput / 3.281
    }
}

var inchCalc: Double {
    let lengthInput = Double(lengthIn1) + Double(lengthIn2)/100
    
    if lengthUnit == 0 {
        return lengthInput * 39.37
    } else if lengthUnit == 1 {
        return lengthInput
    } else {
        return lengthInput * 12
    }
}

var feetCalc: Double {
    let lengthInput = Double(lengthIn1) + Double(lengthIn2)/100
    
    if lengthUnit == 0 {
        return lengthInput * 3.281
    } else if lengthUnit == 1 {
        return lengthInput / 12
    } else {
        return lengthInput
    }
}
```

I thought about using an if else statement every time lengthunit == 0, but I don't know how to return 3 different values that are used at 3 different places. So is there a way this code can be shortened? Or is there a way to return 3 different values from one if statement that can then be used at 3 different places?

Comment: Consider to use [`Measurement`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/measurement) as described [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-convert-units-using-unit-and-measurement)

Comment: How can I use the Measurement struct with my code?
I tried putting it under the `var meterCalc: Double {}`
But it gave me an error that I wasn't returning a double value from a Measurement<unit>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the OP asked for a `Measurement` solution, here we go. I *borrowed* Larme's `combinedValue` property.

```
var combinedValue : Double {
    return Double(lengthIn1) + Double(lengthIn2)/100
}
```

Declare `lengthUnit` as a `UnitLength` value

```
let lengthUnit: UnitLength = .meters
```

The convert method is just one line

```
func convert(_ value: Double, from:  UnitLength, to:  UnitLength) -> Double {
    return Measurement(value: value, unit: from).converted(to: to).value
}
```

And the three calculation properties are

```
var meterCalc: Double {
    return convert(combinedValue, from: lengthUnit, to: .meters)
}

var inchCalc: Double {
    return convert(combinedValue, from: lengthUnit, to: .inches)
}

var feetCalc: Double {
    return convert(combinedValue, from: lengthUnit, to: .feet)
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate the help! This one with `Measurement` is way easier to use!

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with using a `Enum` instead of random `Int` value where you'll have to remember yourself which one is meter, inch or feet.

```
enum LengthUnit {
    case meter
    case inch
    case feet
}
```

And then

```
var lengthUnit: LengthUnit = .meter //(or .inch, or .feet, depending on the initial unit)
```

Now, we can add a switch case, and in Swift, it can handles tuples:

```
func convert(_ value: Double, from initialUnit: LengthUnit, to targetUnit: targetUnit LengthUnit) -> Double {

    switch (initialUnit, targetUnit) {
        case (.meter, inch):
            return value / 39.37
        case (.inch, .meter):
            return value * 39.37
        case (.meter, .feet):
            return value / 3.281
        case (.feet, meter):
            return value * 3.281
        case (.feet, .inch):
            return value / 12
        case (.inch, .feet):
            return value * 12
        default: //It's (.inch, .inch), (.feet, .feet) and (.meter, .meter)
            return value
    }
}
```

Let's factor the line `let lengthInput = Double(lengthIn1) + Double(lengthIn2)/100` which is repeated each time into:

```
var combinedValues {
    return Double(lengthIn1) + Double(lengthIn2)/100
}
```

Then, in use:

```
var feetCalc: Double {
    return convert(combinedValue, from: lengthUnit, to .feet)
}

var inchCalc: Double {
    return convert(combinedValue, from: lengthUnit, to .inch)
}

var meterCalc: Double {
    return convert(combinedValue, from: lengthUnit, to .meter)
}
```

Now, there is already a converter for that [Measurement](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/measurement) in Foundation.framework

Comment: Thanks! This worked flawlessly, I made some changes to the code but it worked perfectly.

How can I use the Measurement instance with my code? I have no idea where to start and how to return a value from it if I use it in `var meterCalc` or any of the variables.

Answer (score 0):

you can return a dictionary or array to return multiple values